# Couldnt locate MSBuild instance to register with OmniSharp after new Unity project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, path, 64-bit, omnisharp

Could someone help me? Im a unity developer and after creating a new project im greeted with this:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 3.5.2022, 20:37:56
    Target: c:\Users\Moris\Unity Projects\The Millon Dollar Idea\The Millon Dollar Idea.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\Moris\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.24.4-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.38.3-beta.74\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 16664

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 0 MSBuild instance(s)
Could not locate MSBuild instance to register with OmniSharp.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to revert Omnisharp to the previous version on C# extension, like his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72410115/10287850

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).