# OmniSharp Error: Found dotnet version 5.0.201. Minimum required version is 6.0.100

Tags: omnisharp

I use VS Code as my IDE. Today I saw in my C# files that I could no longer use things like "Go To Definition/Implementations" or hover over anything to get the path/type etc.

I found my Omnisharp console and saw they updated last night and there is an error:

Error: Found dotnet version 5.0.201. Minimum required version is 6.0.100.

I can't upgrade my dotnet because 6.0 is not compatible with the runtime in my project and on Mac M1, there are a lot of issues running multiple dotnet instances..

I guess its a bit of a rock and a hard place, anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Comment: I reverted OmniSharp to a previous version and it worked fine

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is a recent update to Omnisharp, which is used by the VS Code C# extension. Add this to your settings and restart the editor.

```json
    "omnisharp.useModernNet": false,
    "omnisharp.path": "",
```

Also if you don't have Visual Studio installed you will likely need to install the [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022) to get MSBuild:
[image]

My understanding of the rationale behind this change is an optimization for modern vanilla c# projects over those using older versions (ie Unity). More info in [this issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5120).

Comment: This should really be an accepted answer since it clearly points out the solution + background info to it.

Comment: @Grimm I think for those who don't have VS2022(?) installed, this doesn't actually work either. Doesn't work for me. I don't have rights to install build tools and I need to do some work ;-)

Comment: @PandaWood Are you sure that there isn't another problem? The above mentioned error is in the Omnisharp VS Code C# extension ... I don't think that this belongs to VS too.

Comment: @Grimm Yeah no this is it. I have VS2019v16.3 installed (which is pre .NET5) and I'm working on .NET5 projects with VSCode. This already gets a warning with omnisharp and requires some special config. But when  o# v1.25 came out, I suddenly couldn't do anything - with the same error as OP. Rolling back omnisharp to 1.24 works

Answer (score 29):

Revert your Omnisharp to previous version

[image]

Comment: geez! Why would someone force me to mess with this? It was working just fine until this last update. Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Update 1.25.0 introduces newer OmniSharp build for .NET 6 which does not support non SDK style .NET projects but results in performance improvements.
Fortunately you can disable this in the settings:

[C# Extension Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cpey.png)

Also, the C# extension no longer ships with an included Mono & MSBuild Tools. Download them here: [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build%20tools) 
Worst case, you can revert to an older extension version.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to extensions in VS Code and search for C# Extension

[VS Code Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzP0R.png)

2. Go to C# Extension settings

[C# Extension Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVlfI.png)

3. Disable "Use Modern Net" option.

[Modern Net Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbVxD.png)

4. Restart VS Code

Answer (score 1):

I haved similar problem and i fixed like this:

*Im using win7 and i have VS 2019 IDE which not supporting dotnet 6 cuz of that vs_installer not installing dotnet6 sdk, in result i cant use c# extension v1.25.0 in vs code, because omnisharp needs net6. **I installed [net 6 sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.302-windows-x64-installer) to my win7 and problem is solved**, now i can use c# extension v1.25.0 in vs code.*