# Omnisharp can't start dotnet

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am using VS Code and Unity.

Under the output tab (omnisharp log) I get this error

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 5/27/2022, 3:16:43 AM
    Target: /Users/<my.name>/unity/Test Project 3/Test Project 3.sln

[ERROR] Error: Command failed: dotnet --version
/bin/sh: dotnet: command not found
```

However, when I go the console, I can run dotnet --version just fine

```
dotnet --version
6.0.202
```

I now get the unity console telling me that the print command is invalid, but that error isn't highlighted in vs code.

Update: it seems to work if I open VS Code from the terminal. Doing research, it has something to do with the path. Still unsure why it doesn't normally work.

Comment: Do you run your application and `dotnet --version` command(when it gives output) on the same machine? Maybe you run your application in the Docker container?

Comment: Yes everything is on the same machine

Comment: I will ask if you are using an M1 Mac. Unless you have all binaries in ARM64, such errors are expected.

Comment: MacOS Montgomery 12.1 (21C52) - Macbook Air. I'm glad I found a workaround, but what if I hadn't? I just have to live with errors?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.7. It used to work fine just a few weeks ago.

Comment: @SeanAH Try adding to your user settings file the two lines described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72385697/795016 Then make sure to fully close and reopen VSCode. his solved it for me!

Comment: This should be an answer. I actually did this a while ago to solve a related problem. I didn't check if it solved my original problem at the time, but I now see that I'm not getting it any more.

Answer (score 3):

In your terminal enter: `where dotnet`

Set this directory for `omnisharp.dotnetPath` in your VSCode preferences.

**Update**: For the newer non-omnisharp version, set for `dotnet.dotnetPath`.

Comment: This worked for me. It suddenly stopped working today though. Not sure what I changed before this. Never had to update this before. Thanks for the tip, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

.Net SDKs are available at this path in Program Files: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
Do you have this .net SDK path set in your 'Environment Variables' -> 'System variables' -> 'Path'? If not, try that.